# Is there infinite generated reflexive module?

Tags: modules

Is there infinite generated reflexive module?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, over the ring of integers.  The free abelian group on countably many generators clearly has, as its dual, the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$.  The dual of the latter is, by a theorem of Specker (1950) [maybe already in a paper of Baer, 1937] again the free abelian group we started with, and the canonical embedding is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much! So over an Artin ring all reflexive modules are finitely generated??